# YAML placeholders with kubectl

Tags: yaml, kubectl

I'm using below template in `deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: httpbin-diffy
  labels:
    app: httpbin-diffy
  namespace: {{ Values.namespace.name }}
```

and using separate `values.yaml` for

```
namespace:
  name: diffy
```

when I run  `kubectl apply -f Deployment.yaml`

I get the below error.

`error: error parsing Deployment.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{"Values.namespace.name":interface {}(nil)}`

where I'm going wrong?

Comment: **where I'm going wrong?** -- Mixing helm and kubectl.

Answer (score 3):

Using [Go's template language](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) with a `values.yaml` is a feature of [Helm](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/) that is not native to Kubernetes.  If you'd like to create a templated `deployment.yaml` file, you could use a native tool like `sed` to do find-and-replace before sending to `kubectl`, or could use [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) for a more YAML-aware replacement tool.

```sh
$ cat deployment.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: httpbin-diffy
  labels:
    app: httpbin-diffy
  namespace: PLACEHOLDER

$ yq '.metadata.namespace = "NAMESPACE_VALUE"' deployment.yml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: httpbin-diffy
  labels:
    app: httpbin-diffy
  namespace: NAMESPACE_VALUE
```

That file can either be written to the filesystem and applied with `kubectl apply -f` or could be read from stdin, e.g.

`$ yq '.metadata.namespace = "NAMESPACE_VALUE"' deployment.yml | kubectl apply -f -`