# purpose of PLACEHOLDER entry in kubernetes yaml files

Tags: kubernetes

Why write *non-secret* metadata as `PLACEHOLDER` in kubernetes yaml files? (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72322737/yaml-placeholders-with-kubectl)):

```
namespace: PLACEHOLDER
```

Any reason to replace it with a later `sed` command? why not simply write it inside the yaml file?

Comment: yes, better to write it to Yaml file directly, and perhaps use a tool like kustomize if you e.g. have different environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those values are normally replaced or overridden later, either by sed within a CI/CD pipeline like Jenkins, or (as indicated by the question you linked to) by Helm.

With helm, you can override values within the yamls either with a second yaml, or at the command line using `--set` switches.

So I could have

`helm install nginx --values values.yaml --values values2.yaml`

and the placeholder value in `values.yaml` would get overridden by the value in `values2.yaml`

Placeholders are often used to deliberately break an install is someone tries to install it without passing in the right `values.yaml`

For example:

`helm install my-chart`

Could break because of the placeholder value, but

`helm install my-chart --values production.values.yaml`

would install because the placeholder values are overridden and the chart can install correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, when you see files like this, they might be used in some sort of pipelines to deploy them in multiple clusters. These files, from my prior experience, act like templates when you don't want to go all in with Helm charts for a single ConfigMap or Secret or a different isolated resource. This allows you to replace these placeholders with values corresponding with you cluster, region etc.

Hope this makes sense.